# Why does $u$-substitution require the variable to be injective?

Tags: calculus, substitution

I read this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470411/why-should-the-substitution-be-injective-when-integrating-by-substitution) but I didn't understand it. I expect a simple yet satisfying answer

Why does $u$-substitution require the variable to be injective? What's the reason for that? I didn't understand.

Comment: It doesn't require any injectivity assumptions; see the answer by Christian Blatter

Comment: @user580918 I believe it is a case of *"piecewise injective function"*.

Comment: @Ryan But why does it require injective assumptions if the interval is not split up? Why does it? Why should it be injective in the first place?

Comment: Please Include some details of what you do not understand specifically. Quote the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:I consolidated both answers here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2518470/21813

Answer (score 1):

The general formula
$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(u)\mathrm{d}u=\int_a^bf(g(x))g'(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

is valid even if $g$ is not injective. But most time, we want to write something like
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(u)\mathrm{d}u=\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(x))g'(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

which of course require some inversibility of $g$.

Comment: *"...which of course requires some inversibility of $g$"* — How does this prove that it needs to be **injective**?

Comment: "$g$ is injective" means that $g$ is a bijection on its image, i.e. that $g$ is invertible.