# Rules to choose substitution for definite integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let us consider the integral :$$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}}\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}dx$$

I want to solve it by using the substitution $t=\sin x$.

But I read in a book that the substitution that we make must be **monotonic** in the given domain.

The author even went on to give some examples to justify his statement one of them being $$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}dx$$

Clearly, the substitution $t=\sin x$ does not work here.

Is there a proper result/theorem which would require the substitution to be **monotonic** or **injective**. I can only find examples and counter-examples.

Comment: I believe it is stated this way in Baby Rudin.

Comment: Yes, it is:  it is Theorem 6.17 and 6.19.

Comment: But in the first example the substitution works and the substitution is neither monotonic nor injective

Comment: "If it is monotonic then substitution works" does not mean that if it's not monotonic then substitution will fail.

Comment: The reason it works in this case is that $\sin\frac{2\pi}3=\sin\frac\pi3$ and that $$\int_{\pi/2-a}^{\pi/2+a}\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}dx=0$$

Comment: You can simply split the integral into two, namely over the intervals $(0, \pi/2)$ and $(\pi/2, 2\pi/3)$. The substitution $y = sin(x)$ is in both intervals monotic. So you can  perform both integrations and then add up the results.

Comment: Actually I want to know whether it is NECESSARY for substitution to be monotonic

Comment: No, it is not necessary.

Comment: Extremely relevant Q&As on this topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929380/what-is-wrong-with-the-following-u-substitution/2518470#2518470 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470411/why-should-the-substitution-be-injective-when-integrating-by-substitution?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Maverick Technically, the substitution *must* be injective, at least by the change of variables theorem for $\mathbb{R}^n.$ However, as M.Wind clarified, you can split the integral into parts, such that in every part, your non-injective substitution is injective in each individual part. So in practice, this does not actually matter, and often, it does not affect your computation.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at my replies in the comments to your post for more details, but here, I just aim to explain what is an appropriate method for utilizing substitution to obtain the correct value for the integral. Notice that $$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}3}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{2\pi}3}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ $$=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{2\pi}3}\frac{-\sin(x-\frac{\pi}2)}{1+\cos(x-\frac{\pi}2)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ $$=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}6}\frac{-\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ For the first integral, the substitution $y=\sin(x)$ is injective and results in $$\int_0^1\frac1{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y,$$  while for the second integral, the substitution $y=\cos(x)$ is injective and results in $$\int_1^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}2}\frac1{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y.$$ Therefore, $$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}3}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\frac1{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y+\int_1^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}2}\frac1{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}2}\frac1{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y=\ln\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\right).$$ In this case, it turns out that the direct non-injective substitution gives the same result, but in general, you have to be careful.